# T-SQL Building out columns off a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to figure out how to format/group by out of a table in SQL Server 2008 R2.  I have racked my brain on how to do this, but couldn't come up with a way to do so.  Here is the basic layout of the table

```
Pkey   Account_No     Contact_Date   Flag   Job
1      10001          2013-12-09     y      apple
2      10001          2013-12-10     n      orange
3      10002          2013-12-02     n      apple
4      10003          2013-12-10     y      pear
5      10003          2013-12-11     n      peach
6      10003          2013-12-12     n      apple
```

Essentially what I need to have as the output is somehow group by the Account_No(only distinct Account_No's listed), but then have the contact_dates and flags built out from them ordered by dates.  The columns to build out could theoretically go out forever.  Please see the table below as an example of the output:

```
Account_No     Contact_Date_1   Flag_1   Job_1   Contact_Date_2   Flag_2   Job_2    Contact_Date_3   Flag_3   Job_3
10001          2013-12-09       y        apple   2013-12-10       n        orange   NULL             NULL     NULL
10002          2013-12-02       n        apple   NULL             NULL     NULL     NULL             NULL     NULL
10003          2013-12-10       y        pear    2013-12-11       n        peach    2013-12-12       n        apple
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You want that output on purpose?

Comment: And if an account_no has 5 contact_date values, you want 5 sets of columns, and if an account_no has 26 contact_date values, you want 26 sets of columns? Yikes (no pun intended). Leave this pivoting to the presentation tier.

Answer (score 0):

Good question here. I often come across similar problems while coding reports.

I do something like this-

```
WITH y AS (
SELECT row_number() over (partition by account_no order by contact_date) AS rn,
       pkey
       , account_no
       , contact_date
       , flag
       , job
  FROM x -- assuming the name of your table is x
)
  SELECT account_no,
         MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN contact_date ELSE NULL END) AS contact_date_1,
         MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN flag ELSE NULL END) AS flag_1,
         MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN job ELSE NULL END) AS job_1,
         MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN contact_date ELSE NULL END) AS contact_date_2,
         MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN flag ELSE NULL END) AS flag_2,
         MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN job ELSE NULL END) AS job_2,
         MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN contact_date ELSE NULL END) AS contact_date_3,
         MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN flag ELSE NULL END) AS flag_3,
         MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN job ELSE NULL END) AS job_3
    FROM y
GROUP BY account_no
```

There could be a shorter solution but can't think of it right now.

But beware- this will work for only three contact_date values. For any more values, you will have to add another set of `MAX(..` columns in the `SELECT` list.